# Transform JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, csv

I have PHP code that generates i single line with commas and without end.
to get the my data i used to place:

```
<?php echo trim($matches[0]); ?>
```

With output:

```
data,data,data,data
```

now am using JavaScript to export my data.

```
var externalData = '<?php echo trim($matches[0]); ?>\n'
                 + '<?php echo trim($matches[1]); ?>\n'
                 + '<?php echo trim($matches[2]); ?>';
// and so on...
// split the string into rows, and split each row into cells
var parsed = externalData.split('\n').map(function(row) {
    return row.split(',');
});
</script>
```

and this is how I print my data.

```
<script>document.write(parsed[0][1] || '');</script>
```

with output:

```
data
```

Now i want to make this JS to be php, it will be a lot easy to get my data where i want.
So how can i make the this to be php and not js.

Comment: What have you tried, can you show us some (perhaps not ideally working) php-code?

Comment: Why `document.write(value || '')`? Probably not related but looks weird to me.

Comment: @Pietu1998 i use ` || ''` because i dont want to undefined, i dont need this special code i make to php.

Comment: @Wrikken i have try fgetcsv but i cant make to work, i dont know what variable to set to make fgetcsv to work propertly.

Comment: @user2670708: `explode()` would be PHP's way to `split()` a string, `echo` for output, can you make something with that? If you want your data in JS again, look at `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Wrikken do you know how its going the code? i want to show the data with php, JS is complicated inside the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode($delimiter, $data)` in PHP for `data.split(delimiter)` in JS and `echo $value` in PHP for `document.write(value)` in JS. Also, you can loop through the array with `foreach($array as $value){ ... }`. And, in PHP you can append to an array and even create it implicitly with `$array[] = $new_value`.

```
// parse  $matches to $parsed, as in the JS code
foreach($matches as $value){
    $parsed[] = explode(",", $value);
}
// and now print the desired value
echo $parsed[0][1];
```